# Regular Expression: Filenames

Tags: regex

Extremely new to this and have been trying to figure this out on my own, but no luck.

It seems simple.  I have files that are named either starting with L or P, followed by 6 numbers.  I need to have 2 expressions, one that only reads files starting with L and one that only reads files starting with P.

I have tried using derivatives of `^[K-M]`, `^\L.*`

No luck so far.  Hoping someone can offer a suggestion.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @hichris123 "I have tried using derivatives of `^[K-M]`, `^\L.*`"  I agree it's not that descriptive of what the OP did, but they did make an *attempt* at saying what they tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try `^P\d{6}` and `^L\d{6}`.  The `^` says start at the beginning of the string.  The `\d{6}` matches 6 digits.

If at some point you wanted to match both in one go, you could do `^[LP]\d{6}`.  The `[LP]` says match one of `L` or `P`.

---

If the above doesn't work, you might be working with a more limited regex implementation.  You could try `^P\d\d\d\d\d\d` and `^L\d\d\d\d\d\d` to get the same results.

If that doesn't work, you could try `^P[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` and `^L[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` which should work on all regex implementations.  The `\d` is just shorthand for `[0-9]` anyway.

Comment: That absolutely works when I'm testing it in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ however not working in the program that I it to work in.

Comment: What language are you using?  That's an important detail, because different languages implement different variants of regex.  This assumes Perl regex syntax.  You might consider updating the question with the tag for the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Seth's answer is correct.
If it doesn't matter what comes after the 'P' or 'L' you could also just use `^P` and `^L`.

In the future, you should try testing how regexes match your input strings using a regex tester such as [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) or [Regular Expression Editor](http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html).